# How to convert additional Objective C Frameworks not included in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, webkit, delphi-xe2, freepascal

I want to convert the WebKit framework by following the patterns used in other Objective C frameworks included in Delphi XE2.

I am getting the following error message:

> Project ProjectFM raised exception class EObjectiveC with message 'ObjectiveC class WebView could not be found'.

I have a included the WebKit framework in the Remote Profiles, by adding is follows:
Path: /System/Library/Frameworks
Framework: WebKit

I have followed the pattern found in MacAPI.Foundation.pas to begin translating the WebView.h file as follows:

```
  WebViewClass = interface(NSViewClass)
  ['{0D9F44B7-09FD-4E35-B96E-8DB71B9A2537}']
    {class} function canShowMIMEType(MIMEType: NSString): Boolean; cdecl;
  end;

  WebView = interface(NSView)
  ['{C36D8016-2FCB-49F0-BA1C-C9913A37F9AC}']
    procedure close; cdecl;
  end;
  TWebView = class(TOCGenericImport<WebViewClass, WebView>)  end;
```

Also, does the GUID for the interface have any relevance?

Can anybody provide any guidance as to what steps must be followed to tap into any of the additional objective c frameworks not included in XE2.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: regarding GUID, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992183/are-guids-necessary-to-use-interfaces-in-delphi accepted answer