# How do I check whether an interfaced object implements another interface?

Tags: delphi, oop, interface

I have these interface declarations:

```
IListener = interface
  procedure HandleEvent(AEvent: TMyEvent);
end;

IExtendedListener = interface(IListener)
  ['{85A3456A-D5E5-4F37-ABDD-A75A7B3B494C}']  // required by GetInterface
  procedure HandleExtendedEvent(AExtendedEvent: TMyExtendedEvent);
end;
```

Given an interface reference for something that implements `IListener`, how can I check whether it also implements `IExtendedListener`? I'm using the code below code because it is a compile time error to do something like `if Listener is IExtendedListener then ...`.

```
TSomeClass.Notify(AEvent: TMyExtendedEvent);
var
  Listener: IListener;
  ExtListener: IExtendedListener;
  Obj: TObject;
begin
  for Listener in FListeners do
  begin
    // works but smells funny
    Obj := Listener as TObject;
    Obj.GetInterface(IExtendedListener, ExtListener);
    if Assigned(ExtListener) then
      ExtNotifyee.HandleExtendedEvent(AEvent);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: have a look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.Supports

Comment: Your code does not check whether IExtendedListener inherits from IListener, merely that the instance referenced through IListener also supports IExtendedListener. It in no way says anything about inheritance between the two interfaces.

Comment: `HandleExtendedEvent` has got only one argument in declaration. Why do you want to pass 2 arguments?

Comment: Doesn't checking for a specific "Level" of inheritance defeats the whole purpose of inheriting?

Comment: @MarjanVenema, I asked the question because 'if Listener is IExtendedListener then' will not compile.

Comment: That's fine, just wanted to make sure that you and anybody reading this understand that the code doesn't say anything about inheritance to avoid any possible confusion. Supports is the easiest way to check and get the proper reference. And you need to get a reference specific to the exact interface because interface references cannot be "hard" cast'ed as object references can. Interface inheritance is a whole different ball game from class inheritance.

Comment: From the top of my head (can't check right now, one of my VM servers crashed, so no Delphi VMs at hand), when both interfaces have a GUID, you can use the `is` construct that @MarjanVenema referred to. Hopefully the VM server gets resurrected soon. You might also want to read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992183/are-guids-necessary-to-use-interfaces-in-delphi If anyone can check this sooner than I can, please do.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers, I believe you are mistaken.  I added a guid to TListener but couldn't use `is`.  It would be nice though.

Comment: @LawrenceBarsanti thanks for verifying that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `Sysutils.Supports` to check for a special Interface

```
uses
  SysUtils;

TSomeClass.Notify(AEvent: TMyExtendedEvent);
var
  Listener    : IListener;
  ExtListener : IExtendedListener;
begin
  for Listener in FListeners do
    if Supports( Listener, IExtendedListener, ExtListener ) then
      ExtListener.HandleExtendedEvent( AEvent );
end;
```

Comment: I was cleaning up the code for the question and left the reference to self in.

Comment: @LawrenceBarsanti ok, that make sense to me and did not affect the question :o)

Comment: Probably they did it like that as optimization, but they should still have supported "is" and "as" for interfaces too. They could have check in the compiler if they could optimize "as" followed by "is" with some caching internally of the result of the interface "cast" (done during checking, guess that was needed for COM interfaces)