# Does reference counting still works with Delphi Interfaces when you don't provide a guid?

Tags: delphi

I have the following interface:

```
type IDataAccessObject<Pk; T:class> = interface
   getByPrimaryKey(key: PK) : T;
   //... more methods
end;
```

And an implementation of the interface as follows:

```
type TMyClassDAO = class(TInterfacedObject, IDataAccessObject<integer, TMyClass>)
   getByPrimaryKey(key:integer) : TMyClass;
   // more methods
end;
```

Note that I am **not** providing a `guid` for the interface (because every instantiation of the previous generic interface is a different interface and they should not share the same `guid`). However I am not sure whether that does not break reference counting implemented by `TInterfacedObject`?

Comment: See also [Are GUIDs necessary to use interfaces in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2992183/576719).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reference counting does not rely on a `GUID`, but on `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` method implementations.

Since you inherit from `TInterfacedObject`, reference counting will work for all of your object instances.

The only thing you lose if you don't provide a GUID is the ability to query one interface from another, such as in calls to the `Supports()` function, `QueryInterface()` interface method, and the `is` and `as` operators.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!